# Why is VLC minimized while playing video or audio?

Tags: 11.10, vlc

I have installed VLC from ubuntu software center I have used it perfectly for some days but now while i try to play a audio or video its get minimized to system tray.

Tried

1. I have clicked on the vlc icon in the tray but no use with that menu.
2. Tried to play a video from vlc through terminal but its still
   minimized to try.
3. Uninstalled and installed from different sources(downloaded from
   [vlc official site](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)) but no use.

Comment: will you please tell me where that reset preferences button will be?

Comment: Did you by chance use the Accessibility Options like Orca Screen Reader and such? Because I did that a couple of weeks back and it triggered this issue.

Comment: sorry I don't know will you please tell me how to rectify this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can I suggest you reset to the standard interface and click the *Reset Preferences* button available through the *Tools - Preferences* menu option

[image]

You can also reset the configuration from a terminal command:

```
vlc --reset-config
```

---

Double check that vlc configuration has been completely regenerated:

```
mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc_backup
```

Comment: do you know how to open the preferences window through terminal

Comment: dont think you can open the preferences window via a terminal... but you can reset the config as per my updated answer.

Comment: sorry i have tried that "vlc --reset-config" also but no use same problem continues.

Comment: even the icon in the launcher was disappeared i have tried several options by reading from the "vlc --help" command but no use

Comment: ok - if you apply my last edit and this doesnt work, then I would consider its something else that you recently installed.  Any that comes to your mind that you have installed in the last few days?

Comment: i have just installed the secret maryo chronicles game and after 6days i have booted into the ubuntu because i have to use photoshop so i moved to windows 7 (dual booted)

Comment: this solves my problem "mv ~/.config/vlc ~/.config/vlc_backup" thanks